# How bad is it to inject the IoC container as a dependency?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container, ioc-container, factory

I know that injecting an IoC container as a dependency is usually considered a bad thing, because it basically the same as the Service Locator anti-pattern. However there is a case where I think it might make sense, especially since I don't see an easy way around it.

Consider these classes :

```
// domain class
public class Foo
{
}

// ViewModel
public class FooViewModel
{
    [Dependency]
    public IBar Bar { get; set; }

    [Dependency]
    public IBaz Baz { get; set; }

    private readonly Foo _foo;

    public ViewModel(Foo foo)
    {
        _foo = foo;
    }
}

// Dependencies used by ViewModel
public interface IBar { void Frob(); }
public interface IBaz { void Fiddle(); }
```

Now suppose I have to display a list of `FooViewModel`, built from a list of `Foo`. To create an instance of `FooViewModel` from a `Foo`, I have the following choices:

- just call the constructor and set the dependency manually:

  ```
  var vm = new FooViewModel(foo) { Bar = _bar, Baz = _baz };
  ```

  this is impractical, because:

  - the object that creates the `FooViewModel` needs to have `Bar` and `Baz` as dependencies, even if it uses them only to create `FooViewModel`
  - if I add a new dependency to `FooViewModel`, I'll have to update the code everywhere I create an instance of it.

  Both issues could be solved by creating a factory, but that factory would need to be written and maintained. In this very basic scenario it wouldn't be an issue, but for a large real-world app, it can become quite cumbersome if there are many factories with many dependencies.
- use the IoC container to resolve `FooViewModel`:

  ```
  var vm = _container.Resolve<FooViewModel>(new ParameterOverride("foo", foo));
  ```

  This takes care of the dependencies, but then I have to use the container in my ViewModel layer, which is bad (or is it?).

I was thinking about a compromise: create a factory class that only has the container as a dependency, and uses it to build the `FooViewModel`:

```
public class FooViewModelFactory
{
    [Dependency]
    public IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }

    public FooViewModel CreateFooViewModel(Foo foo)
    {
        return Container.Resolve<FooViewModel>(new ParameterOverride("foo", foo));
    }
}
```

This way I have a very simple factory that is easy to maintain, and the only classes that have the container as a dependency are the factories, not the actual business-related code.

**Do you see any drawback in this approach? Am I missing a better/simpler solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually adopted an approach similar to what I had shown in my question:

```
public class FooViewModelFactory
{
    [Dependency]
    public IUnityContainer Container { get; set; }

    public FooViewModel CreateFooViewModel(Foo foo)
    {
        var vm = new FooViewModel(foo);
        Container.BuildUp(vm);
        return vm;
    }
}
```

The use of `BuildUp` makes the code more readable than using `ParameterOverride`.

Using the container as a dependency might be a code smell, but in this case it definitely makes the code simpler, and I haven't noticed any drawback in a few months of using this approach. (I inject the container only in factories, though).

Ideally, the approach suggested by BatteryBackupUnit would have been better, but without runtime code generation, it's impractical, and generating the code at compile time is too much work for too little benefit, so I chose the more pragmatic approach.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that service locator is an anti-pattern.

That said, the question you've posted can only be answered by yourself and does actually not fit the Q&A Format of Stackoverflow: It's highly opinion based. It might be a better fit on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

The important thing about deciding on this is evaluating and understandig all possible solutions and their side effects. Side effects may also include concerns about the people who are maintaining the code. Are they capable of understanding it? How do they work? Can you educate them?

So i gather the question you should actually ask is: how else can this problem be solved?
Then try it out and see for yourself how the solutions compare.

Putting too much value on tips like "don't do that" (without further explanation and understanding) will only result in .. no growth! Which is basically the worst thing that can happen (not learning anything ever => always bad design).

For your specific question i would like to pitch in with a possible solution:

Use an auto-generated factory. This is very similar for the factory type you have suggested, but it limits your coding to the parameters you want to supply. All the others you don't have to care about.
For example, Ninject features the Factory extensions where you can do stuff like:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public FooViewModel(Parameter parameter, Bar bar, Nice nice) { ...}
}

public interface IFooViewModelFactory
{
    FooViewModel Create(Parameter parameter);
}

kernel.Bind<IFooViewModelFactory>().ToFactory();

FooViewModel instance = kernel.Get<IFooViewModelFactory>()
      .Create(new Parameter("my parameter"));
```

that's basically all of the code you got to maintain. Adding / changing / removing a dependency @ `FooViewModel` does not result in a change of the factory (unless you do actually want to provide the parameter).

A drawback may be, that that part of the object graph - including the dependencies - is only instanciated when the factory `.Create(..)` method is called. This is dependent on the way the auto-factory-generating code is implemented.
In ideal Dependency Injection the object graph is built at the composition root, at the start of the application, and everything is built at once. That way you'll detect IoC configuration issues right away when you start the application, not later on when you use a specific feature and click some button - which will call some factory.

As far as i know for unity there's some kind of extension that was ported from Castle.Windsor - `TecX.Unity.Factories`, see http://outlawtrail.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/auto-generated-factories-with-unity/.
Then there's also http://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.TypedFactories, which is basically the same.

You might even be content with Unity's "Automatic Factory" support (`Func<>`). I actually don't know whether it's able to handle parameters, i'm quite new to unity myself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right, this question would probably be a better fit for Programmers.SE or CodeReview.SE. I like the idea of a factory generated by the IoC container, I'll look into it!

Comment: OK, generated factories aren't gonna work for me, unfortunately... My app is a Windows Store app, and `System.Reflection.Emit` is not available on this platform, which means that dynamic code generation is limited to `System.Linq.Expressions`; not enough to generate a new type... I can try to auto-generate `Func<>`, but it's not quite the same; some of my factories have more than one method.

Comment: Well if you're willing to put some work into it, you could look into https://github.com/BrunoJuchli/Unity.StaticProxyExtension (disclaimer: i'm the author), which was specifically built because of that. I did not get around to create a Unity factory generator, yet. If you'd be willing to give it a try, please create an issue on the github issue tracker detailing how the interface should look. I might get around to write it this weekend.

Comment: oh and i think i did not configure package creation correctly, so i'll probably have to change a thing or two to make it work on some of the PCL platforms, especially MonoDroid and MonoTouch.

Comment: Looks interesting... I don't know anything about IL weaving, though; I'll have to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

If all the view models can live with the same instance of `IBar` and `IBaz`, then you can simply define a factory that has those instances as dependencies:

```cs
public class FooViewModelFactory
{
    private readonly IBar _bar;
    private readonly IBaz _baz;

    public FooViewModelFactory(IBar bar, IBaz baz)
    {
        _bar = bar;
        _baz = baz;
    }

    public IEnumerable<FooViewModel> CreateViewModels(IEnumerable<IFoo> foos)
    {
        return foos.Select(f => new FooViewModel(f) {Bar = _bar, Baz = _baz});
    }
}
```

I don't see anything bad about instantiating view models by hand since you have to pass different implementations of `IFoo` anyway.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you missed the point of my question... I already mentioned this approach in my question, and the problem is that it's hard to maintain if you have a lot of dependencies. What I'm looking for is feeback about my usage of the IoC container.